PCB digital sound input and output
I've designed a simple 3-band equalizer circuit. I've used 3.5 mm audio input connected with computer via 3.5 mm audio jack for input, and basic small speaker for output.
In all my references, many circuits did work well with connection with audio jacks and speakers. But mine did not print out the sound through the output speaker. Also, in contrast to my expectations that oscillator will show waveforms when I connect prove next to 2.2 μF DC blocking capacitor, it has shown constant 2V DC signal. How can I handle this? Do I need a voltage buffer between the sound input and the DC blocking capacitor to properly give out the sound signal?



This looks like an entirely analog circuit. Where does the "digital sound" in your title come from?

What are the power supply voltages at J3 and J4?  Also, the circuit should have power decoupling capacitors located as close as possible to pins 4 and 11.

Make sure the capacitor is not faulty. You might want to try a different capacitor to see if the problem persists.

J3 and J4s were for the VCC and VEE of op amp LM324N. I've tried power decoupling capaticors using 100uF. It still had serious noises, but anyway it had cancelled out for a little. Also, I guess the DC voltage problem was due to the mismatch of the power required for speaker. When I replaced speaker into earphone, the circuit worked properly. Many thanks for all the comments everyone.
